# explain the options of readlink command

Tags: readlink

Can someone please explain me following options of `readlink` command in simple language:

```
   -f, --canonicalize
      canonicalize  by  following  every symlink in every component of
      the given name recursively; all  but  the  last  component  must
      exist

   -e, --canonicalize-existing
      canonicalize  by  following  every symlink in every component of
      the given name recursively, all components must exist

   -m, --canonicalize-missing
      canonicalize by following every symlink in  every  component  of
      the  given  name recursively, without requirements on components
      existence
```

Comment: Try the [info page](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/readlink-invocation.html#readlink-invocation). Also,  they have some [test scripts](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/tests/readlink) (`can-f.sh`, `can-e.sh` and `can-m.sh`) that should give you an insight on how those options work.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think it's quite self-explanatory, so I don't really know the part which sounds ambiguous for you...
Let's see with an example:

### --canonicalize

```
$ mkdir /tmp/realdir
$ mkdir /tmp/subdir
$ ln -s /tmp/realdir /tmp/subdir/link
$ cd /tmp

$ readlink -f ./subdir/link/nonexistentdir/
/tmp/realdir/nonexistentdir

$ readlink -f ./subdir/link/nonexistentfile.txt
/tmp/realdir/nonexistentfile.txt
```

Whatever the options are, `readlink` will:
  - translate the relative path to absolute path
  - translate the symlink name to the real path

And as you can see above, with `-f`, `readlink` doesn't care if the last part of this path (here `nonexistentfile.txt`) exists or not.

If another part of this path does not exist, `readlink` will output nothing and will have a return code different than 0 (which means an error occured). See:

```
$ readlink -f /tmp/fakedir/foo.txt
$ echo $?
1
```

### --canonicalize-existing

If you try the same with `-e`:

```
$ readlink -e ./subdir/link
/tmp/realdir

$ readlink -e ./subdir/link/nonexistentfile.txt
$ echo $?
1
```

With `-e`, in case any of the path component doesn't exist, `readlink` will output nothing and will have a return code different than 0.

### --canonicalize-missing

`-m` option is the opposite of `-e`. No test will be made to check if the components of path exist:

```
$ readlink -m ./subdir/link/fakedir/fakefile
/tmp/realdir/fakedir/fakefile

$ ln -s /nonexistent /tmp/subdir/brokenlink

$ readlink -m ./subdir/brokenlink/foobar
/nonexistent/foobar
```

Comment: the thing that confused me was why would someone need `-e` and `-m` options?

Comment: @edwardtorvalds for instance, you may need a path which depends on an external device which is not mounted yet, or a log file which is not yet created because the service is not up...

Answer (score 0):

> that confused me was why would someone need -e and -m options?

From the kernel source code ./scripts/kconfig/merge_config.sh (the script takes a list of config fragment values, and merges them one by one):

```
if [ -z "$KCONFIG_CONFIG" ]; then
    if [ "$OUTPUT" != . ]; then
        KCONFIG_CONFIG=$(readlink -m -- "$OUTPUT/.config")
    else
        KCONFIG_CONFIG=.config
    fi
fi
```

KCONFIG_CONFIG receive path to .config file which may not yet exist.